# Распарсить таблицу с заголовком в tr

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Часть таблицы

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="feature_block_name">
    <strong>Основные характеристики</strong>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="feature_name">Адрес производителя</td>
    <td class="feature_value">Ariston Thermo SPA. Viale Aristide Merloni, 45 60044 Fabriano AN, Italia.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="feature_block_name"><strong>Конструкция</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="feature_name">Дисплей</td>
    <td class="feature_value">Есть</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" class="feature_block_name"><strong>Основные</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="feature_name">Вид</td>
    <td class="feature_value">газовый</td>
    </tr>
```

Вид какой требуется получить

```
Основные характеристики|Адрес производителя|Ariston Thermo SPA. Viale Aristide Merloni, 45 60044 Fabriano AN, Italia.
Конструкция|Дисплей|Есть
```

и так далее по таблице.

Мой кусочек кода который работает не правильно.

```
$table = $html_product->find('#product_teh tbody',0);
$tr = $table->find('tr');
foreach($tr as $rowa) {
    $td_feature_block_name = $rowa->find('td.feature_block_name');
    $td_feature_name = $rowa->find('td.feature_name');
    $td_feature_value = $rowa->find('td.feature_value');
    $theData[] = $td_feature_block_name[0]."|".$td_feature_name[0]."|".$td_feature_value[0];

}
$theData = implode($theData,PHP_EOL);
```

Получается  на выходе

```
Основные характеристики||
|Адрес производителя|Ariston Thermo SPA. Viale Aristide Merloni, 45 60044 Fabriano AN, Italia.
Конструкция||
|Дисплей|Есть
```

Comment: ну дак вы разорались, почему на выходе получается то что получается? если разобрались, то почему сразу не написли, чтобы люди тут голову не ломали. если нет, то заметьте у вас _Основные характеристик_ в первой `tr` идут   а _АдресПроизводителя_ уже в следующей

Comment: @teran да тут мой косяк. Только как решить то проблему )

Answer (score 0):

в вашем случае нужен классический цикл по строкам с шагом равным 2.

Если приведенный вами html-код обернуть в `<table>...<table>` для примера, то выглядеть оно будет как то так:

```
$html = str_get_html($txt);
$rows = $html->find("tr");
$rcount = count($rows);

for($idx = 0; $idx < $rcount; $idx+=2){
    $name = $rows[$idx]->find("td",0)->plaintext;

    $fname  = $rows[$idx + 1]->find(".feature_name",0)->plaintext;
    $fvalue = $rows[$idx + 1]->find(".feature_value", 0)->plaintext;

    echo "$name|$fname|$fvalue\n";
}
```

Comment: Получается полная каша )
http://prntscr.com/iy5b3u
http://prntscr.com/iy5b9l

Comment: @Andry и чем эта каша отличается от вашего вида, который вы хотели получить?

Comment: @Andry где то вероятно сбивается структура таблицы. первые строки ведь нормально выглядят.